# Program soft-locking when calling second* function

Tags: c++, function

So, I'm practising my C++ code by writing a program that creates a matching-pairs game out of a grid with user-specified size. To do this I've separated each action (initialising the grid, drawing the grid, hiding the pairs and finding the pairs from user input) into a function.
Unfortunately, at some point - I can't tell when or how - the program began failing to call the second* and subsequent functions. After calling `drawGrid`, it should move on to `hidePairs` immediately - however, it just stops at that step. The cursor in the command window keeps blinking, so the program's running just fine, but nothing I can do will make it progress.
I've checked via debugging, and it does successfully execute `drawGrid`and moves on to the next line in `main`, but then no more code gets executed. What am I doing wrong?

*EDIT: third function, it successfully draws the grid, THEN stops before hiding the pairs. Unnecessary calls-by-reference removed and all functions added for clarity. My bad :P

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>


void drawGrid(int gridX, int gridY, char gridArray[][30]);
void hidePairs(int gridX, int gridY, char pairsArray[][30], int *numPairs);
void findPairs(int gridX, int gridY, char gridArray[][30], char pairsArray[][30], int *numPairs);
void initialiseGrid(int gridX, int gridY, char gridArray[][30], char pairsArray[][30]);

int main()
{
    int gridX, gridY, numPairs;

    //Ask user for gridX(width) and gridY(height)
    std::cout << "Please enter the width and height of the grid you want to use." << std::endl;

    bool gridIsNotEven = true;
    while (gridIsNotEven == true)
    {
        std::cin >> gridX >> gridY;
        if ((gridX*gridY) % 2 == 0)
        {
            gridIsNotEven = false;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << std::endl << "The grid produced by these two numbers has an odd number of spaces." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    if (gridX*gridY > 30)
    {
        std::cout << "This grid is larger than recommended." << std::endl;
    }
    gridX++;
    gridY++;
    char gridArray[30][30];
    char pairsArray[30][30];
    numPairs = ((gridX*gridY) / 2);

    //Func : initialiseGrid
    initialiseGrid(gridX, gridY, gridArray, pairsArray);

    //Func : drawGrid
    drawGrid(gridX, gridY, gridArray);

    //Func : hidePairs
    hidePairs(gridX, gridY, pairsArray, &numPairs);

    //Func : findTreasure
    findPairs(gridX, gridY, gridArray, pairsArray, &numPairs);

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

void drawGrid(int gridX, int gridY, char gridArray[][30])
{
    int printX, printY;

    //For(printX = 0, printX < gridX, printX++)
    for (printY = 0; printY < gridY; printY++)
    {
        //For(printY = 0, printY < gridY, printY++)
        for (printX = 0; printX < gridX; printX++)
        {
            std::cout << gridArray[printX][printY] << " ";
        }
        //END FOR

        //Print new line
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    //END FOR
}

void hidePairs(int gridX, int gridY, char pairsArray[][30], int *numPairs)
{
    int pairsMade, halfPair, curPairX = 0, curPairY = 0;
    char pairSymbol = '!';

    for (pairsMade = 0; pairsMade < *numPairs; pairsMade++)
    {
        halfPair = 0;
        while (halfPair < 2)
        {
            curPairX = rand() % gridX;
            curPairY = rand() % gridY;
            if (pairsArray[curPairX][curPairY] == '?')
            {
                pairsArray[curPairX][curPairY] = pairSymbol;
                halfPair++;
            }
        }
        pairSymbol++;
    }
}

void findPairs(int gridX, int gridY, char gridArray[][30], char pairsArray[][30], int *numPairs)
{
    int guess1X = 0, guess1Y = 0, guess2X, guess2Y, printChar, pairsFound = 0;
    //Display pairs
    char pairSymbol = '!';
    printChar = 0;
    std::cout << std::endl << "The following symbols will be used in the grid:" << std::endl << std::endl;

    while (printChar < *numPairs)
    {
        std::cout << pairSymbol << std::endl;
        pairSymbol++;
        printChar++;
    }
    //while ((guessX != treasureX) OR(guessY != treasureY))
    while (pairsFound != *numPairs)
    {
        //  User input : guessX and guessY
        std::cout << std::endl << "Please enter the co-ordinates of your first guess (e.g. 'X Y')" << std::endl << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();

        std::cin >> guess1X >> guess1Y;
        gridArray[guess1X][guess1Y] = pairsArray[guess1X][guess1Y];
        drawGrid(gridX, gridY, gridArray);

        std::cout << std::endl << "Please enter the co-ordinates of your second guess (e.g. 'X Y')" << std::endl << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();

        std::cin >> guess2X >> guess2Y;
        gridArray[guess2X][guess2Y] = pairsArray[guess2X][guess2Y];
        drawGrid(gridX, gridY, gridArray);

        if (guess1X > gridX || guess1X < 1 || guess1Y > gridY || guess1Y < 1)
        {
            std::cout << std::endl << guess1X << ", " << guess1Y << " does not lie inside the grid. Try again." << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        else if (gridArray[guess1X][guess1Y] == gridArray[guess2X][guess2Y])
        {
            pairsFound++;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << std::endl << "Pair not matching" << std::endl << std::endl;
            gridArray[guess1X][guess1Y] = '?';
            gridArray[guess2X][guess2Y] = '?';
        }

        //      END IF
    }
    //Print ‘Success! etc.’
    std::cout << std::endl << "Success! You found all the pairs!" << std::endl << std::endl;
}

void initialiseGrid(int gridX, int  gridY, char gridArray[][30], char pairsArray[][30])
{
    int printX, printY;
    for (printY = 0; printY < gridY; printY++)
    {
        for (printX = 0; printX < gridX; printX++)
        {
            if ((printX == 0))
            {
                gridArray[0][printY] = printY + '0';
                pairsArray[0][printY] = printY + '0';
            }
            else if ((printY == 0))
            {
                gridArray[printX][0] = printX + '0';
                pairsArray[printX][0] = printX + '0';
            }
            else
            {
                gridArray[printX][printY] = '?';
                pairsArray[printX][printY] = '?';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you pass all parameters as pointers?

Comment: It's just a habit I've gotten into. True, many of them could function as pass-by-value, but even then that doesn't seem to be the issue here.

Comment: For what input does it fail? `if (gridX*gridY > 30)` should be `if (gridX > 30 || gridY > 30)` but thats also not a reason for a crash.

Comment: Okay, I've changed any unnecessary references into value passes, and made array names match in the declarations, definitions and passes. Output is still the same, with it just stopping after drawing the grid the first time. (I made a mistake earlier, when I said it stopped BEFORE `drawGrid` was called)

Comment: you probably have an infinite loop somewhere in the code you didnt show. What happens if you put a `cout` directly after drawing the grid?

Comment: Why do you do `gridX++` and `gridY++` in `main`? That could cause issues in the future. EDIT: Nvm, I think I get it, you want to have table headers above and left.

Comment: Yup, seems to be an infinite loop in the hidePairs function. I'll look into it, thanks for the help! Odd that it didn't show up in the loop last time I debugged... eh, whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialised the number of pairs to `numPairs = gridX * gridY / 2`, but that size (`gridX`, `gridY`) contains also the header column and row, that do not play  a role in the pairing.
So to fix this, your `numPairs` should be `(gridX-1) * (gridY-1) / 2`.
Else, the pairs will have been exhausted, but the pairing function is still looking! This is your infinite loop.

I also advise you to find a better name for `gridX` and `gridY` to indicate that the headers are counted, or to be very careful in the rest of your code that you understand what `gridX` and `gridY` mean and that the grid only starts being an actual thing at index `1` rather than index `0`.

Comment: Thank you! Ah, the ol' off-by-one issue. I'm honestly surprised anyone could even understand my code, it's so badly laid out! I will take on board that advice about variable naming, it sounds like that could help me out a lot in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: @ChipBiscuit It was actually quite readable code; things nicely split into functions, decent variable names all-round (except for this one confusion), **no globals** but rather parameter passing making it so much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

It seams it fails only if you add numbers 30 and higher caused by array size 
I dont know your settings but ensure you have compiler setting of language standard like GNU C++11

it should work

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's an infinite loop in the hidePairs function. It's not reading the correct co-ordinates in the pairsArray, so there are spaces it never fills in. And since the loop is only set to end when all unused spaces are filled, it never stops.
Advice for others: always sanity-check your loops!